# Docker - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch

Tags: asp.net, docker, ssl, docker-compose

I am trying to automatically create ssl certificates for ui and api using docker. But I am getting an exception

`The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors`

Here is my docker compose

```
`version: '3.4'

services:
integrationtestingbase:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
ports:
  - "9000:443"
  - "9001:80"
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
  - Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=api.pfx
  - Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=

integrationtestingwebappbase:
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}ui
build:
  context: .   
  dockerfile: ui/Dockerfile
ports:
  - "9002:443"
  - "9003:80"
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
  - Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=ui.pfx
  - Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=

 sqlserver:
image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:latest
environment:
  MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "Password123!"
  ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
ports:
  - "1433:1433"
volumes:
  - ./path/to/appsettings.json:/app/appsettings.json

 certificate_generation:
 build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.cert_generator
  volumes:
  - ./certificates:/certificates
```

`

here is the docker file to generate the certificate

```
`FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add openssl

# Create certificates directory
RUN mkdir /certificates

# Generate API certificate
RUN openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout 
/certificates/api.key -x509 -days 365 -out /certificates/api.crt - 
subj "/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=Dummy 
Corp/OU=Engineering/CN=api.example.com" \
  && openssl pkcs12 -export -out /certificates/api.pfx -inkey 
/certificates/api.key -in /certificates/api.crt -password pass: \
  && if [ -f "/certificates/api.pfx" ]; then echo "API Certificate 
Generated Successfully"; else echo "Failed to generate API 
Certificate"; fi

# Generate UI certificate
RUN openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout /certificates/ui.key -x509 -days 365 -out /certificates/ui.crt -subj "/C=GB/ST=London/L=London/O=Dummy Corp/OU=Engineering/CN=ui.example.com" \
&& openssl pkcs12 -export -out /certificates/ui.pfx -inkey /certificates/ui.key -in /certificates/ui.crt -password pass: \
&& if [ -f "/certificates/ui.pfx" ]; then echo "UI Certificate Generated Successfully"; else echo "Failed to generate UI Certificate"; fi

# Copy certificates to host machine
RUN mkdir -p /host_certificates/api && cp /certificates/api.pfx /host_certificates/api/ \
&& if [ -f "/host_certificates/api/api.pfx" ]; then echo "API Certificate Copied Successfully"; else echo "Failed to copy API Certificate"; fi

RUN mkdir -p /host_certificates/ui && cp /certificates/ui.pfx 
/host_certificates/ui/ \
&& if [ -f "/host_certificates/ui/ui.pfx" ]; then echo "UI 
Certificate Copied Successfully"; else echo "Failed to copy UI 
Certificate"; fi
```

`

Here is my razor page trying to talk to the api

`namespace IntegrationTestingWebAppBase.Pages
{
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
public List Tenants { get; private set; }

```
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpClient = httpClient;

 
        //var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        //handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;


        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var apiUrl = "https://host.docker.internal:9000/api/tenant/getall";

         

            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(apiUrl);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var tenants = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<Tenant>>();

                if (tenants != null)
                {
                    Tenants = tenants;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Handle null response if needed
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle unsuccessful response if needed
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException is System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException authenticationException)
            {
                // Handle SSL/TLS error
                _logger.LogError("SSL/TLS error: {0}", authenticationException.Message);
                // You can log or handle the authenticationException appropriately
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle other HTTP request exceptions
                _logger.LogError("HTTP request error: {0}", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle other exceptions
            _logger.LogError("An error occurred: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
}
```

`

See above. I expect to not get this error and the ui and api to be able to communicate.

Comment: You are generating the certificate with api.example.com as Common Name (CN). You must replace it with the correct host name of your api server

Comment: @Luty the host name is host.docker.internal?

Comment: Looking at your code, yes this is the host name